# Keyboard down key doesn't trigger until 4-5 presses, then triggers indefinitely till some other key is pressed

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have gone through all general procedures such as removing, reinstalling drivers, using external keyboards, etc and the behaviour stays. So the key doesn't fire unless i press it 4-5 times, and then it starts firing indefinitely. To stop it i have to press some other key (or even the same key but through another keyboard or the on-screen keyboard, doesn't matter). This is on windows 10, on an HP laptop, quite new.

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen when booting from a live USB, e.g., [Win PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) or a live Linux USB, e.g., [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)?

If those work without issue, then there is definitely a problem in Windows 10 **or an additional application**, rather than in hardware. Try these in the order below, from easy to more dsifficult and aggressive.

1. Are there any [accessibility features](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/discover-windows-accessibility-features-8b1068e6-d3b8-4ba8-b027-133dd8911df9) in use? Shut them.
2. Are any applications installed that intercepts key events, such as AutoHotkey or Clavier+? Disable them.
3. Has the machine been set up by corporate IT, who may have installed additional software? Check with IT staff.
4. If it's your PC, does BIOS have a seting for special use of that key? Shut it.
5. If it's your PC, use [DISM and SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) to check and repair the Windows OS.
6. If it's your PC, reinstall [Windows from ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), keeping files. *Make a disk image before doing this* to fall back, lest something go wrong.
7. Unlikely, but vaguely possible, check for (inept) malware using [an offline scanning tool](https://www.lifewire.com/free-bootable-antivirus-tools-2625785).